# CoreData: search for entries with relationship to another entrie

Tags: core-data, ios7

Since I don't know how to describe my problem exactly I did not find any suitable answer. I hope I can explain it right :)

I have three entities: Player, Event and EventPlayerState. The EventPlayerState has a n-1 connection to the Player and Event and some additional attributes.

For one function, I need all EventPlayerStates with connection to the event X. I have the object of the event X, but I  don't know how to search in CoreData with an object.

The same with code:

```
NSMutableArray *eventplayerstates = [fetched results] NSMutableArray
*selectedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [eventplayerstates count]; i++) 
{    
   if([eventplayerstates[i].hasEvent objectID] == [event objectID])
   {
      [selectedObject addObject:eventplayerstates[i]];    
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with a predicate:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
entityForName:@"EventPlayerState" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSPredicate *eventPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY events == %@", eventX];
[fetchrequest setPredicate: eventPredicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
// make sure to test for the error
```